# What is the difference between "I have three people in my family" vs "I have three people in my household"?

Tags: word-choice, ambiguity

What is the difference between "I have three people in my family, my wife and our son" vs "I have three people in my household, my wife and our son" ?

Does "in the my household" mean we live together while "in my family" does not necessarily mean that?

Comment: There is no ambiguity here. Try comparing the dictionary definitions for *family* and *household*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "household" can include non-family members, such as the maid, servant, foster children, or perhaps even an exchange student who is living in the home for a period of time.

A "household" *may not* include all of the family members, as some may have grown and moved out of the home such as to go to college or to start their own families.

Essentially, "household" addresses those living in the home, whereas "family" addresses those joined together by genetic (birth) or legal ties (marriage, adoption, etc.) by which they are considered relatives.  They are different terms, but can often overlap.